# Is there a way to set a key to be the "first" key in an object?

Tags: javascript

This is a kind of strange question but is there a way to set a key to be the "first" key in an object?

For example say I have an object:

```
object = {
 'name': bob,
 '3': 3,
 'id': 1
}
```

And if I call `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object)`, is there a way I can fix the order to be something like `['id', '3', 'name']`?

Comment: Properties don't really have a usable ordering in JavaScript. The current spec says that the properties should be returned (by `Object.keys()` for example, or a `for ... in` loop) in the order in which they were created, but relying on that in an actual body of code is highly fragile.

Comment: You can just `getOwnPropertyNames()` and then sort them out. Or you technically can (**but please don't**) override `getOwnPropertyNames` with your own implementation, which will call native implementation. In general, it is a strange question indeed :)

Comment: Right the most robust thing to do is impose your own ordering via some reliable external mechanism depending on your application.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone!

Comment: It isn't at all a strange question :) there are plenty of times you want to do that. Just `sort` the properties after you call `.getOwnPropertyNames`

Comment: If you need an ordered dictionary well-defined by the spec, use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 1):

Properties order in objects is not guaranteed in JavaScript.
details: [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

UPD: Take a look at maps 
ref: https://hackernoon.com/what-you-should-know-about-es6-maps-dc66af6b9a1e

Comment: Seems like a duplicate vote to close, rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a array order, then use map:

```js
var object = {
 'name': 'bob',
 '3': 3,
 'id': 1
};
var order = ['id', '3', 'name'];
var result = order.map((current,index,order)=>{
    return object[order[index]];
},0);
console.log(result);
```